# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception for Chrome

Tags: java, selenium

```
public void openBrowser()
    {
        if(!isBrowserOpened)
        {
            if(config_getproperty("browserType").equals("MOZILLA"))
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            else if (config_getproperty("browserType").equals("IE"))
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            else if (config_getproperty("browserType").equals("CHROME"))
            {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe" );
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }

            isBrowserOpened=true;
            String waitTime=config_getproperty("default_implicitWait");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Long.parseLong(waitTime), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
```

this code was working till yesterday but suddenly after restart it stopped working showing session not established.
I tried all other solutions..Replaced Chrome exe with latest version replaced webdriver with 3.0 but still it was not working.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue started showing up after chrome Version 54.0.x updates. Remove the older chromedriver from your path and update your chromedriver to 2.24. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

more information required like error log from console, which would have explained in detail, it just seems to be version compatibility issue downgrade the v and see whether things are good

Answer (score 0):

```
npm rm chromedriver
npm install chromedriver@2.25.1
```

What @Keshav said.  Basically, you need an updated version of the Chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

Update ChromeDriver https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/ . This should solve the issue